# SQL ServerでCSVファイルを読み取りInsertすると日本語が「?」で格納される

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server

SQL Server 2014 Express

規定の言語:Japanese
照合順序：Japanese_CI_AI
CSVファイル:Shift-JIS

Visual C# Windows Formアプリケーションにて
System.Data.SqlClientを使用し、以下のようにcsvファイルをBulk Insert
し、SQL Server Management Studioで結果を確認した所日本語が「?」で格納されてしまっていました。

```
BULK INSERT table_name
FROM 'file.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', FIRSTROW = 1)
```

解決策を調べてみたのですが、改善出来ず質問させていただきました。
他に見直す必要のある項目はございますでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CODEPAGE=932`をWITHの中に追加すればいけると思います。

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: CODEPAGE=932をWITHに追加したところ解決致しました。
ありがとうございます。